# Three.js Rotate Texture

Tags: three.js

I have a texture applied to a mesh I can change the offset with

```
mesh.material.map.offset.set
```

I can change the scaling with

```
mesh.material.repeat.set
```

so my question is, how can I rotate texture inside a plane?

### Example:

From This:

[image]

To this

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use 2D canvas as a texture

demo:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1236764/temp/stackoverflow_20130525/index.html

example code

```
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh;

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, width / height, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 100;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( width, height );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var img = new Image();
img.onload = createMeshThenRender;
img.src = 'img.jpg';

function createMeshThenRender () {
    var imgWidth = imgHeight = 256;
    var mapCanvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    mapCanvas.width = mapCanvas.height = 256;

    // document.body.appendChild( mapCanvas );
    var ctx = mapCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
    ctx.translate( imgWidth / 2, imgHeight / 2 );
    ctx.rotate( Math.PI / 4 );
    ctx.translate( -imgWidth / 2, -imgHeight / 2 );
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight );

    var texture = new THREE.Texture( mapCanvas );
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 50, 50, 1, 1 ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
            map : texture
        } )
    );
    scene.add( mesh );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: That was really helpful. It's way easier to rotate/scale images directly on the canvas instead of using an image.

Answer (score 3):

three.js does not have a UV editing utility, so you either have to edit the `geometry.faceVertexUvs` manually, or rotate your image in an image editing program. I'd suggest the latter.

three.js r.58

Comment: I'll have to fiddle with the UV's then. The latter defeats the purpose of what I'm building.

Answer (score 3):

three.js r121

In the newer version of the three.js, you can directly set rotation and rotation center of texture.

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture( ... );
texture.rotation = Math.PI/4;
texture.center = new Vector2d(0.5, 0.5); // center of texture.
```

Answer (score 2):

three.js r85

For those looking to actually "**rotate UVs**" on a Plane sitting in XY plane (default plane) using a ShapeBufferGeometry or PlaneBufferGeometry.

```
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(24,24);
var planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: yourTexture}));
scene.add(planeMesh);
rotateUVonPlanarBufferGeometry(45, planeMesh);

function rotateUVonPlanarBufferGeometry(rotateInDeg, mesh){
  if(rotateInDeg != undefined && mesh){

    var degreeInRad = THREE.Math.degToRad(rotateInDeg);
    var tempGeo = mesh.geometry.clone();
    var geo;

    if(tempGeo instanceof THREE.BufferGeometry){
        geo = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(tempGeo);
    }else{
        console.log('regular geometry currently not supported in this method, but can be if code is modified, so use a buffer geometry');
        return;
    }

    // rotate the geo on Z-axis
    // which will rotate the vertices accordingly
    geo.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(degreeInRad));

    // loop through the vertices which should now have been rotated
    // change the values of UVs based on the new rotated vertices
    var index = 0;
    geo.vertices.forEach(function(v){
      mesh.geometry.attributes.uv.setXY( index, v.x, v.y );
      index++;
    });

    mesh.geometry.attributes.uv.needsUpdate = true;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions were not good to me, a little bit old. That's simple solution worked for me (Three.js 125)

```
imgData = canvasCtx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
texture = new THREE.DataTexture( imgData.data, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height, THREE.SRGB );
texture.rotation = Math.PI;
texture.center = new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 0.5); // center of texture.
mymaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                                map: texture,
                                alphaTest: 0.5,
                                transparent: true,
                                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                            });
```