# make three.js skybox from tilemap

Tags: javascript, three.js, skybox

I can make a three.js skybox using 6 separate image files.  But I want to be able to build a skybox from a single image made up of  tiles.

For example if I have a composite tiled image as source (see (http://www.zen226082.zen.co.uk/STACK_EXCHANGE/Giant_A.jpg)... i dont have enough rep to post it here :-(.

I can load the composite image into a canvas and copy each tile into a cache buffer and then send them into a Three.js materials array.  The materials are then used to make a skybox.

However there are two problems.

Problem 1 is that the composite image needs to be flipped.  I can do this easilly in a graphics app like Paint.net but it would be nice to be able to do it programmatically in javascript/three.js.

Problem 2 is that Three.js requires that the tiles for Y+ and Y- also need to be rotated 180 degrees.  This is difficult (for me) to do in a graphics application.  For example here is a composite tiled image after modification to suit the Three.js code which I have been using  (http://www.zen226082.zen.co.uk/STACK_EXCHANGE/Giant_B.jpg) (Horrible!)

My Question = Is there some way that I can perform a 180 degree rotation on the two tiles after extracting them from the composite image and before passing them into the skybox construction.

EDIT (10th August 2014)
The Question should be "How to make a three.js skyBox from a single image file made up of 12 equal-sized tiles".

Here is the code I have been using:-

```
    var skyBoxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(skybox_sidelength,skybox_sidelength,skybox_sidelength); 
    var skyBoxMaterialArray = [];

    var widthOfOnePiece  = 2048/4;//...i.e. 512
    var heightOfOnePiece = 1536/3;//...i.e. 512
    var numColsToCut = 4;
    var numRowsToCut = 3;

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "TRI_VP_files/images/SOW_skybox_2048_1536_v7.jpg";
    image.onload = SOW_F_cutImageUp;
    //... NB canvas origin is Top Left corner, X is left to right, Y is top to bottom

    function SOW_F_cutImageUp() {
        var imagePieces = [];

        for(var xxx = 0; xxx < numColsToCut; ++xxx) 
        {
            for(var yyy = 0; yyy < numRowsToCut; ++yyy) 
            {
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = widthOfOnePiece;
                canvas.height = heightOfOnePiece;
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(image, 
                xxx * widthOfOnePiece, yyy * heightOfOnePiece, widthOfOnePiece, heightOfOnePiece, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                imagePieces.push(canvas.toDataURL());

            }
        }
        //...  expected sequence of face view directions  = ["xpos", "xneg", "ypos", "yneg", "zpos", "zneg"];

        for (var iii = 0; iii < 6; iii++)
        {
                 if (iii == 0) imagePiece_num = 4 //... xpos
            else if (iii == 1) imagePiece_num = 10//... xneg
            else if (iii == 2) imagePiece_num = 6 //... ypos
            else if (iii == 3) imagePiece_num = 8 //... yneg
            else if (iii == 4) imagePiece_num = 1 //... zpos
            else if (iii == 5) imagePiece_num = 7 //... zneg

            skyBoxMaterialArray.push
            ( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
                (   {map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imagePieces[imagePiece_num]),
                    side: THREE.BackSide}));

            //window.open(imagePieces[imagePiece_num], "Here is the toDataURL() cached image", "width=512, height=512");
            //alert ("Continue");
        }
    }//... end of function.

    var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( skyBoxMaterialArray );
    var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeometry, skyBoxMaterial );
    scene222.add( skyBox );
```

Comment: There a lot of moving parts here. Are you using WebGLRenderer? See how the cross is extracted in this three.js example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shaders_ocean.html. In the example, `MeshShaderMaterial` is used instead of `MeshFaceMaterial`.

Comment: @WestLangley.  Many thanks. The cubeMap stuff does what I need...in PC/Win7/Firefox...but in PC/Win7/Chrome the webgl_shaders_ocean.html demo crashes my PC..I took out the water mirror stuff and now it fails at Three.js line 508 with "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded." Also fails to run in PC/Win7/Opera.  I have been using three.js/webgl  in Chrome/Opera for 12 months without problem.

Comment: 1. The crashing requires a different post... 2. See if this alternate approach works for you: Use your `MeshFaceMaterial` approach, and set `skyBoxGeometry.scale.set( -1, 1, 1 );` You may have to swap `xpos` with `xneg`.

Comment: @WestLangley.  Presume you meant "skyBox.scale.set..." (i.e. the mesh, not the geometry which throws an error).  Anyway with skyBox.scale.set(-1,1,1) the sky box is not displayed at all.

Comment: `skyBox.scale.set( -1, 1, 1 )`, and for each material in the materials array, `material.side = THREE.FrontSide;`

Comment: @WestLangley. OK (with using source Giant_A.jpg and also remapping my imagePiece_num values) that now makes displayed skybox good for tiles:- px,nx,pz,nz.  The py,ny tiles are mapped to the right "faces" but now they need to be rotated by 180 degrees around the scene Y-axis.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a _simple_ live example?

Comment: A *NOT* simple example = http://www.zen226082.zen.co.uk/TRI_VPs_v65_CYLINDERS.html (best with Chrome).  I am trying to make a simpler live version.

Comment: You are using a version of three.js that is a year old. Please upgrade to the current version r.68.

Comment: http://www.zen226082.zen.co.uk/3D_Skybox.html uses r.68. Four SkyBox methods, three work OK. Fourth method relates to original question but r.68 doesnt like my old code... Three.js line 452 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ". Stumped at present :-(.

Comment: 1. Debug with the un-minified version `three.js` -- not `three.min.js`. 2. Clean up your example code - it is too hard to follow. 3. Only cases 3 and 4 which use the horizontal cross are relevant to your question. 4. You are almost there...

Comment: Thanks. OK done as requested see zen226082.zen.co.uk/3D_Skybox.html.  Error Three.js R.68 Line 19797: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I guess R68 doesnt like the line...map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imagePieces[imagePiece_num]). Tried different approaches without success.

Comment: @WestLangley - Hold fire. Just found I needed to wait for image processing before defining mesh.  I will re-code the example and advise on original problem status.

Comment: http://www.zen226082.zen.co.uk/3D_Skybox_v3.html uses R.68 and displays the remaining part of the original problem i.e. the ypos and yneg faces need to be rotated 180 degrees around the Y-axis.  I have seen a way of doing rotations in canvas (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727547/three-js-rotate-texture, yomotsu answer )but you may have a slicker way?

Comment: @WestLangley. OK http://www.zen226082.zen.co.uk/3D_Skybox_v4.html, uses R.68. Works OK.  It does the necessary rotations of the ypos and yneg face textures.  It also does the flipping as per your design.  Thats all I need.  Thanks greatly for your patient assitance.  I will put up an answer (unless you want to do one?).

Comment: I think you are making it more complicated than it needs to be. If the image in the center of the cross is associated with the positive-z side of the box, then you do not have to do any 180 degree spinning.

Comment: Ah yes you are right of course. "The center of the cross is associated with the *** positive-z side *** of the box".  No need for any 180 degree rotations. Doh!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Question should be "How to make a three.js skyBox from a single image file made up of 12 equal-sized tiles".

(This answer achieved with greatly appreciated assistance from WestLangley).

Some key points:-

- Assume the tiles in the source image are arranged and referenced thus:-

  ```
  //... Personal             Source image               Desired in-scene        Required
  //... tile numbering       [column, row]              xyz positions of 6      sequence numbers in 
  //... scheme               tile coordinates            tiles to be used.      Three.js material array 

  //... [ 0] [ 3] [ 6] [ 9]  [0,0] [1,0] [2,0] [3,0]   [  ] [py] [  ] [  ]      [ ] [2] [ ] [ ]     
  //... [ 1] [ 4] [ 7] [10]  [0,1] [1,1] [2,1] [3,1]   [nx] [pz] [px] [nz]      [1] [4] [0] [5]     
  //... [ 2] [ 5] [ 8] [11]  [0,2] [1,2] [2,2] [3,2]   [  ] [ny] [  ] [  ]      [ ] [3] [ ] [ ]
  ```
- The tile at the centre of the "cross" corresponds to the view looking from the skyBox origin in the Z_positive direction.
- (That makes spinning by 180 degrees unneccessary).
- In definition of material use... side: THREE.FrontSide
- To prevent mirror images of the source tiles, "flip" them using... skyBox.scale.set( -1, 1, 1 )
- To ensure that images are fully processed  the function F_cutImageUp extends to include creation of the skyBox mesh
- This works for the current latest Three.js release (R.68).
- This code does not use MeshShaderMaterial, more powerful (but demanding) WebGL code example is available at http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shaders_ocean.html
- The webgl_shaders_ocean.html code example also includes a more efficient tile-cutting and sequencing algorithm.

SkyBox Generation Code (to be inserted in the THREE.js Initialisation function).

```
var skybox_sidelength = 10000;
var skyBoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( skybox_sidelength, skybox_sidelength, skybox_sidelength); 

var skyBoxMaterialArray = [];

var numCols = 4, numRows = 3; //... assume any source image is tiled 4 columns(x) by 3 rows(y)
//... NB canvas origin is Top Left corner, X is left to right, Y is top to bottom

//... We use the following mapping scheme to reference the tiles in the source image:-
//...
//... Personal             [x,y] tile coordinates    xyz positions            Required tile       
//... tile numbering                                 of tiles in scene        sequence in Three.js 
//...                                                                         array 

//... [ 0] [ 3] [ 6] [ 9]  [0,0] [1,0] [2,0] [3,0]   [  ] [py] [  ] [  ]      [ ] [2] [ ] [ ]     
//... [ 1] [ 4] [ 7] [10]  [0,1] [1,1] [2,1] [3,1]   [nx] [pz] [px] [nz]      [1] [4] [0] [5]     
//... [ 2] [ 5] [ 8] [11]  [0,2] [1,2] [2,2] [3,2]   [  ] [ny] [  ] [  ]      [ ] [3] [ ] [ ]                           

var image_file = "3D_Skybox_files/Giant_A.jpg", tile_width = 512, tile_height = 512;    
var IP_image = new Image();
IP_image.onload = F_cutImageUp; 
IP_image.src = image_file; //... horizontal cross of 6 WYSIWYG tiles in a 4x3 = 12 tile layout.

function F_cutImageUp() 
{ //... cut up source image into 12 separate image tiles, numbered 0..11

    var imagePieces = [];
    var item_num = -1;

    for(var xxx = 0; xxx < numCols; ++xxx) 
    {
        for(var yyy = 0; yyy < numRows; ++yyy) 
        {
            var tileCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            tileCanvas.width  = tileWidth;
            tileCanvas.height = tileHeight;

            var tileContext = tileCanvas.getContext('2d');

            tileContext.drawImage( 
                IP_image, 
                xxx * tileWidth, yyy * tileHeight, 
                tileWidth, tileHeight, 
                0, 0, tileCanvas.width, tileCanvas.height);

            imagePieces.push(tileCanvas.toDataURL());

        }
    }

    //... Required sequence of tile view directions  = ["xpos", "xneg", "ypos", "yneg", "zpos", "zneg"];

    for (var iii = 0; iii < 6; iii++) //... select the right tiles for the 6 different faces of the sky box
    {

        //... we associate the centre tile (4) of the cross with the zpos direction
             if (iii == 0) imagePiece_num =  7;//... xpos
        else if (iii == 1) imagePiece_num =  1;//... xneg
        else if (iii == 2) imagePiece_num =  3;//... ypos
        else if (iii == 3) imagePiece_num =  5;//... yneg                                       
        else if (iii == 4) imagePiece_num =  4;//... zpos
        else if (iii == 5) imagePiece_num = 10;//... zneg

        skyBoxMaterialArray.push
        ( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
            ({      map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imagePieces[imagePiece_num]),
                    side: THREE.FrontSide // <== not intuitive
            })
        );

        //... Just for checking image pieces are created OK
        //window.open(imagePieces[imagePiece_num], "Here is the toDataURL() cached image " + //imagePiece_num, "width=512, height=512");
        //alert ("Displayed imagePiece_num: " + imagePiece_num);

    }  //... end of tile selection

var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( skyBoxMaterialArray );                         
var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeometry, skyBoxMaterial );
skyBox.scale.set( -1, 1, 1 ); // <== not intuitive
scene.add( skyBox ); 

}//... end of F_cutImageUp function <== note function includes skyBox mesh creation.
```

Comment: Just found this official example of how to build skyMap using 6 different files...http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_panorama.html  (for Canvas, not webGL).