# Can you create a CubeTexture from a single image?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was wondering if there was a way to create a `CubeTexture` from a single image in Three.JS.

My project currently has panoramas in a single image as a 2x3 cubemap.

`CubeTextureLoader`'s `.load` parameter requires six image URLs for a `CubeTexture`. Ideally I don't want to load all six of them and just load the one image.

Things I've tried:

- Loading a `CubeTexture` with the image 6 times via `CubeTextureLoader` and altering the width/height arribute of the images loaded in.
- Loading a `Texture` with a portion of the image via the `getTexturesFromAtlasFile` function in [this Three.JS example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_cube) and overwriting the `image` attribute of a `new CubeTexture()` with the six images that were loaded.

The end result I hope for is assign the `CubeTexture` to `scene.background`. It feels like loading the image onto an inversed cube like in the above Three.JS example might be the best workaround for now.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25224912/1461008) will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, but that answer loads the image onto an inversed cube like the workaround I mentioned. My question is if we're able to map it onto a `CubeTexture`, which I'm still not sure if it is currently possible.

Comment: You can load one image for the cube, but then you have to set uv for each vertex by yourself so a shader would know how to map it for each face.