# Rotating a texture using PointCloudMaterial

Tags: three.js

When I used `CanvasRenderer` and `SpriteMaterial`, I was able to set a texture's rotation using the `rotation` attribute in the `material`.  So, say for instance the texture is a cone, and I want to rotate it by 180 degrees:

```
material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
    map         : texture,
    transparent : true,
    rotation    : Math.PI
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work with `PointCloudMaterial` in the `WebGLRenderer`.  For example:

```
material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
    depthWrite    : true,
    alphaTest     : 0.1,
    map           : texture,
    transparent   : true,
    vertexColors  : THREE.VertexColors,
    rotation      : Math.PI
});
```

So how can I go about rotating a texture with `PointCloudMaterial` and a `PointCloud` mesh?  Note that in both instances, the `texture` is loaded as a base64 string, as follows:

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
var texture = new THREE.Texture(image);

image.src = /* The base64 string */
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `canvas` to do this, following the pattern described at [Three.js Rotate Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727547/three-js-rotate-texture).  This pretty much worked like a charm.