# Three.js: Rotating the image at startup

Tags: 3d, three.js, rotation

`var FrontSide = new materialClass( { color: 0xffffff, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'front.jpg' ) } );`

When uploading an image, I want to rotate it immediately by 90 degrees. What needs to be done and how can it be done?

Please advise.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Rotate the _texture_? Rotate the _object_? _What have you tried_? Please review [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, include any relevant code, code that you have tried, and any errors. See: [`How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747250/4045502). Or, as an option, you can use `THREE.ShaderMaterial()` with a [fragment shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XlsGWf) to rotate your texture.

Comment: Speech about the texture ...
And a good big example was given, but I thought there was an easier method in one line, like: "MakeRotate" or something similar

Comment: There's a `THREE.DoWorkForMe()`, are you looking for something similar?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

A ported shader (from shadertoy to three.js):

```
var vertShader = `
    varying vec2 vUv; 
    void main()
    {
        vUv = uv;
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    }
`;

var fragShader = `
  uniform float iGlobalTime;
  uniform sampler2D iChannel0;
  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main(){
    vec2 uv = vUv;
    float rot = iGlobalTime; //radians(90);
    uv-=.5;

    mat2 m = mat2(cos(rot), -sin(rot), sin(rot), cos(rot));
    uv  = m * uv;
    uv+=.5;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(iChannel0, uv);
  }
`;
```

and uniforms for it:

```
var uniforms = {
  iGlobalTime: {
    value: 1.0
  },
  iChannel0: {
    value: new THREE.Texture()
  }
};
```

Then we'll load a texture, like this:

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.setCrossOrigin("");
textureLoader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg", function(texture){
  texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  uniforms.iChannel0.value = texture;
});
```

Gather them together:

```
var planeMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: uniforms,
  vertexShader: vertShader,
  fragmentShader: fragShader
});
var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2);
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, planeMat);
scene.add(plane);
```

And the animation loop will be like this:

```
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var delta = 0;

render();
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  delta += clock.getDelta();
  uniforms.iGlobalTime.value = delta;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

three.js r85

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/b0pv5ea9/) example